DSolve don't resolve the ODE
DSolve returns the same equation without any information. Does that mean that my ODE doesn't have a solution? If so do you know how to use a numerical approach.
Fh = 10; 
Fm = 5;  
R = 1;   
h = 0.5; 
M = 2;  
g = 9.8; 

DSolve[
  {
    \[Theta][0] == 0, 
    \[Theta]'[0] == 0,
    \[Psi][0] == 0, 
    \[Psi]'[0] == 0, 
    \[CurlyPhi][0] == 0, 
    \[CurlyPhi]'[0] == 0 ,
    
    \[Theta][t] \[Theta]'[t] \[Psi]'[t] + \[Theta]'[t] \[CurlyPhi]'[t] + \[Theta][t] == -2 h Fh - (R/(4 h^2)) * Fm * \[Theta][t] - 2 h M g \[Theta][t], (* Équation (1) *)

    \[Theta]''[t] + \[Psi]''[t] \[Theta][t] + \[Psi]'[t] \[Theta]'[t] == (R/(2 h)^2) * Fh \[Theta][t] - 2 h * Fm + M g R, (* Équation (2) *)

    \[Psi]''[t] + \[CurlyPhi]''[t] == 2 h R \[Theta][t] * ((R^2) \[CurlyPhi]'[t] + (R Fm) + (M g R)/(2 h )) (* Équation (3) *)
  },
  {\[Theta][t], \[Psi][t], \[CurlyPhi][t]}, (* Variables à résoudre *)
  t (* Variable temporelle *)
]


Please can you edit your question and put your code in a form we can copy and paste into our Mathematic notebooks? This can be done by using the curly brackets in the question toolbar. I will try out your problem if you do this.

You should really write each ode in its own as equation. Also write each initial/BC. Next, use DSolve and use the name of each equation. No need to write one very long command where you write everything in it all at once. Looking at the ode's most likely there is no analytical solution as these are coupled and nonlinear. (you have the dependent variables multiplying each others). Try NDSovle

Hello, welcome to MMA.SE, then, as mentioned by Hugh, please show us the code text rather than a screenshot of it. And, as mentioned by Nasser, it should be straightforward to solve the problem with NDSolve. The question will be reopened once it meets the standard of the site.

Only two of the ODE have the 2nd derivatives of the three variables. Differentiating the first one fixes that problem, but DSolve still balks. NDSolve complains of a singularity at t=0. AsymptoticDSolveValue produces an approximation (series expansion at t=0).
